# Slim 3 Framework Rest Nested Routes

Tags: slim, slim-3

Is there a way to do this:

```
1. $app->get('/phonenumbers', \PhonenumbersController::class . ':index');
2. $app->get('/users/1/phonenumbers', \PhonenumbersController::class . ':index');
```

Would like the second route to resolve to:

```
$app->get('/phonenumbers?user_id=1', \PhonenumbersController::class . ':index');
```

I basically need the user_id available as a request param.
Is this possible in Slim3? Without introducing .htaccess rewrites.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can add parameter in path, that will be available in `request`

```
$app->get('/users/{user_id}/phonenumbers', \PhonenumbersController::class . ':index');

...

class PhonenumbersController
{
    public function index($request, $response)
    {
        $request->getAttribute('user_id');
    }
}
```